# Spark - creating a DataFrame from an external table

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a table in Databricks Delta located in the following path `/mnt/common-data/main/metrics`. I've also created an External Hive table `main.metrics` in Databricks pointing to the location. And I know at least two ways for creating a DataFrame in this case:

```
val metricsDf = spark.read.format("delta").load("/mnt/common-data/main/metrics")
.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

val metricsDfFromTable = spark.table("main.metrics")
.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

What are the pros and cons between the two and is there a difference performance-wise?

Comment: are you creating table after mounting the location?

Comment: @MaheshGupta yes, when the location already exists

Comment: so I think it will give the same result because of lazy evaluation.